# Actualizar una UDF(user defined function) como una función nativa de Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente problema; resulta que necesito hacer cálculos con múltiples tablas de distintas hojas de un libro para lo cual cree una UDF de vba, el calculo lo realizó sin problemas, pero la UDF no se actualiza tal como lo hacen las funciones nativas de excel como "SUMA", "SUMAPRODUCTO", etc. Y necesito realizar una actualización cuando hay cambios porque necesito evidenciar los cambios( El libro es un modelo de planificación y por lo tanto cualquier cambio debe verse reflejado).

-Tengo otra UDF que se actualiza ya que el cálculo final lo realizo con una función nativa(sumproduct).
-Actualmente utilizo el método "application.volatile"(al inicio del código de la función) pero es muy engorroso ya que actualiza cada vez que realizo un cambio en el libro. Hasta ahora este método es lo único que realiza lo que necesito pero con el inconveniente del tiempo de cálculo cada vez que hay cambios en el libro.

Así que si hay una manera de actualizar el resultado de la función, cuando hay cambios en sus argumentos(tal como lo hacen las funciones nativas de Excel) seria genial.

Gracias!.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definidos los argumentos de las funciones? A lo mejor viendo el código alguien te puede dar una solución.

Comment: Como "range" o "variant", el código es un poco extenso, pero he realizado muchas pruebas y lo que me falta es algún método u orden. El porblema de fondo es que las UDF no se actualizan como lo hacen las nativas a menos que el resultado de la UDF sea igual a alguna función nativa de excel. Por ejemplo la otra función que e sirve busca el indice y después realiza "SUMAPRODUCTO" sobre un rango que defino con el indice encontrado y otros parámetros.

Comment: Si tienes definidos los argumentos como Range, tu UDF debería aplicarse sobre el propio Range que introduzcas, a no ser que el propio código de tu función actúe siempre sobre los mismos rangos.  pero sin ver el código, no puedo decirlo.

Comment: Dame unos minutos para editar el código ya que es extenso y debo hacer el asunto del espaciado, gracias por la ayuda,.